# Java applications on Mac using Java7, have a limited window width

Tags: java, macos, swing

I'm developing a desktop application for Mac.  When I run the application using Java6 it works fine, but when I run it using Java7, the application window  seems to be limited to a width 1024 pixels (i.e. when it starts the window is 1024px wide, and can't be expanded/dragged to make it wider).  I've tried all sorts of ways to adjust the size (setting window state to maximized, explicitly setting the width, etc.).  I've also tried changing where I set the Window size, but so far no luck.

I have tried searching for anyone who has had similar problems, but have not had much luck.  The only real hit I got was from an OTN discussion forum: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2617106, but there is no resolution and the discussion seems to be archived so I can't reply to it.

If anyone out there has come across this issue, I'd love to hear about it.

Environment:

Operating System: Mac OS X 10.7.5

Java Version: 1.7.0_55 (Oracle Corporation)

New Information:

Have found a related bug report in OpenJDK: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8046008?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:changehistory-tabpanel

This seems to indicate that it is a problem for Mac OS X 10.7.5, which I am using.

Comment: We are probably going to see some code.

Comment: Sounds like you're using something like `setResizable(false)` and/or `setMaximumSize` on the frame

Comment: Good suggestions, but I'm not using setResizable(false) or setMaximumSize on the Frame.  If I use the exact same code but run using Java6 it works fine;  it seems to be a problem with Java7 on mac.  It also runs fine on Windows using Java7.